# Listening on .info/connected does not always notify when there's a disconnection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

We have a client app written in React and Typescript, which uses Firebase JS SDK v9.23.0.
We are using the [Firebase presence solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence), which mainly includes:

1. Using onDisconnect so the RTDB server sets an RTDB node with the presence status.
2. Synching the presence status from the RTDB node to a Firestore document using Cloud Function.
3. Locally, we listen on .info/connected to trigger the onDisconnect, as well as setting the status on Firestore local cache. We also use it to notify the user on local disconnection.

We see a very strange behavior.
The onDisconnect fires on the BE side, triggerring the presence status change to the RTDB node, and then to the Firestore document.
However there's no change in the status of the local connection - meaning nothing is triggerred by the listener on .info/connected.
To add to it, it seems like there's is a real network issue, as the Firestore changes are not reflected in the web-app (the onSnapshot listener does not fire).

The impact is that in some cases the server indicates a disconnection, but the user has no clue that's the case.

It would be great to understand why, and more over, how exactly does listening on .info/connected work, especially for identifying disconnections.

I'm not able to reproduce it myself, only to see it in production logs, but will share some relevant code (a bit manipulated, for simplification).

Presence mecahnism on the client side:

```
const syncPrecense = async (sessionId: string, participantId: string) => {
   const reconnectHandler = async (): Promise<void> => {
      // Update the participant status in RTDB
      await set(
         ref(
            getDefaultRTDatabaseInstance(),
            `/sessions/${sessionId}/participants/${participantId}/status`
         ),
         {
            presenceStatus: PresenceStatus.ACTIVE,
            lastPresenceChangeTime: databaseServerTimestamp,
         }
      );

      // We update the participant in Firestore directly, in order to update the local cache, in case Firestore server is not connected
      await updateDoc(
         doc(
            getFirestoreInstance(),
            `sessions/${sessionId}/participants/${participantId}`
         ),
         {
            presenceStatus: PresenceStatus.ACTIVE,
            lastPresenceChangeTime: firestoreServerTimestamp,
         }
      );
   };

   onValue(
      ref(getDefaultRTDatabaseInstance(), '.info/connected'),
      async (snapshot) => {
         const isOnline = snapshot.val() === true;
         bi.log(`Participant local presence online status: ${isOnline}`);
         if (!isOnline) {
            // When disconnection is identified locally, we update the local Firestore cache, so the participant itself will know he's disconnected
            await updateDoc(
               doc(
                  getFirestoreInstance(),
                  `sessions/${sessionId}/participants/${participantId}`
               ),
               {
                  presenceStatus: PresenceStatus.DISCONNECTED,
                  lastPresenceChangeTime: firestoreServerTimestamp,
               }
            );
            return;
         }
         // When the local participant is connected, we're determining what to do when disconnect and reconnect will happen.
         // When disconnected, the RTDB SERVER will set the presenceStatus of the ref to disconnected

         onDisconnect(
            ref(
               getDefaultRTDatabaseInstance(),
               `sessions/${sessionId}/participants/${participantId}/status`
            )
         )
            .set({
               presenceStatus: PresenceStatus.DISCONNECTED,
               lastPresenceChangeTime: databaseServerTimestamp,
            })
            .then(reconnectHandler)
            .catch((error) => {
               bi.error('Failed to set onDisconnect handler', error);
               throw error;
            });
      }
   );
};
```

Note that in the participants logs, I don't see the local status changing to offline.

Cloud Function code which syncs RTDB presence status to Firestore:

```
const isPresenceStatusStillAccurate = async (
   statusSnapshot: DataSnapshot,
   statusFromDb: PresenceRecord
) => {
   const updatedSnapshot = await statusSnapshot.ref.once('value');
   const updatedStatus = updatedSnapshot.val() as PresenceRecord;
   return (
      updatedStatus.lastPresenceChangeTime <=
      statusFromDb.lastPresenceChangeTime
   );
};

onValueWritten(
   {
      instance: DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME,
      ref: '/sessions/{sessionId}/participants/{participantId}/status',
   },
   async (event: DatabaseEvent<Change<DataSnapshot>>) => {
      const change = event.data;
      const statusSnapshot = change.after;
      const presenceStatus = statusSnapshot.val();
      // Ignore deleted
      if (!statusSnapshot.exists()) {
         return;
      }
      const isStillAccurate = await isPresenceStatusStillAccurate(
         statusSnapshot,
         presenceStatus
      );
      if (!isStillAccurate) {
         return;
      }
      await firebaseInstance()
         .firestore()
         .doc(`sessions/${sessionId}/participants/${participantId}`)
         .update(presenceStatus);
   }
);
```

On the backend logs (and in other places), I see that the status in RTDB and in Firestore was changed to offline.

On another place in the client, I'm listening on participant status, but the client does not receive the update, which means he's really disconnected:

```
onSnapshot(
         doc(
            getFirestoreInstance(),
            `sessions/${sessionId}/participants/${participantId}`
         )
         (snapshot) => {
/// ... handle participant changes
         }
      );
```

Comment: Did you implement the Cloud Function to mirror the RTDB presence data into Cloud Firestore? Note that the code in the documentation in section [Updating Cloud Firestore globally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#updating_globally) is wrong, it is not Cloud Function code. The corrrect code for the Cloud Function is to be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/cd8938b1a7f688b236e9ad02964e140bc61e73a3/Node-1st-gen/presence-firestore/functions/index.js).

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec. Yes. I implemented the CF to mirror the presence data to Firestore, and also aware of the bug in the documentation :-)
This logic is running for us for over 2 years, so it's not a new implementation.

Comment: That sounds odd indeed, although not impossible. We'll definitely need to see a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to say more about what may be going on here though. Especially the debug logs from the client that falsely stays connected might be interesting.

Comment: Added code samples and explanations on the logs I see and don't see. Hope it's suffice.